# How do I filter filtered data?

Tags: python, csv, filter

For example, there are customers that have invoice numbers. Some customers have multiple invoice numbers.

I already filtered out the unique number of customers by doing:

```
m = list(set(map(lambda x: x.Name + data)))
print("There are", len(m), "customers")
```

How do I say how many females and males there are? If a customer is repeated more than once, the gender should only be counted once.

**Sample data**
Columns in csv are as follows: `state, first name, last name, gender, age, invoiceNo`.

```
state   firstname   lastname    gender  age invoiceNo
TX  Jane    DOE Female  52  36524
TX  Jane    DOE Female  52  65142
NY  John    Williams    Male    68  24536
```

How would I find the average age?

```
 m = customer(row[0], row[1] + " " + row[2], row[3], int(row[4]), int(row[5]))
    data.append(m)

m = list(set(map(lambda x: x.Name + data))
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Can you include a sample of your input data? Also, you might want to look into the [pandas package](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for data analysis.

Comment: Thank you jakub! I added  what i did so far. I am trying not to use pandas. learning my foundations first :)

Comment: if you create pairs/tuples/lists `(name, gender)` then they will be uniq and then you can filter them by `gender` `(pair[1])`

Comment: BTW, `set(map(lambda))` is ugly IMO. It's nicer to use a set comprehension: `list({x.Name for x in data})`

Comment: A sample of your input data should include several lines of actual data, not just the names of the fields in the CSV file (possibly on the first line of the file).

Comment: @Furas - i like this idea. I am trying to avoid using imported functions like counter because I am trying to learn foundations first. Can someone elaborate on this?

Comment: you can start with `m = list(set(map(lambda x: (x.Name, x.Gender), data))` to get uniq names but still have access to genders. And later you can count  `males = sum(x[1] == 'gender' for x in m)` and `females = len(m) - males`

Comment: Why did you remove your code? That removes all the context from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make a dict of each customer's gender and count the occurrences. The nature of a dict means that duplicates will be removed. You can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do the counting for you.

```
from collections import Counter

genders = {x.Name: x.Gender for x in data}
count = Counter(genders.values())
print(count)  # -> Counter({'Female': 1, 'Male': 1})
```

Note: This assumes that names are unique, based on how you built `m`.

Comment: The OP specified that if a customer appears more than once, the gender should be counted once.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to avoid using imported functions since i am still trying to learn basics :) good to know for the future though!

Comment: @jakub I fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

One can create a dictionary mapping the name to gender. Then, one can get the counts of each unique gender. This assumes that each customer has a unique name. We can use a dictionary because it, by design, does not allow duplicate keys. That means that even if a name occurs more than once, it will not be duplicated in the dictionary.

One could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (it is part of the standard library after all), but if one insists, the counts can be computed in other ways. In the example below, I demonstrate the use of `sum` over a sequence of boolean values. `True` and `False` are equal to 1 and 0, respectively.

```py
class Customer:
    def __init__(self, state, name, gender, age, invoiceNo):
        self.State = state
        self.Name = name
        self.Gender = gender
        self.Age = age
        self.Invoice = invoiceNo

customers = [
    Customer(state="CA", name="John Doe", gender="male", age=50, invoiceNo=123),
    Customer(state="TX", name="Jane Smith", gender="female", age=40, invoiceNo=401),
    Customer(state="CA", name="John Doe", gender="male", age=50, invoiceNo=680),
    Customer(state="MA", name="Peter Apple", gender="male", age=30, invoiceNo=1124),
]

# This is a dictionary comprehension. We create a dictionary
# on one line. Very cool...
name_to_gender = {customer.Name: customer.Gender for customer in customers}
print(name_to_gender)
# {'John Doe': 'male', 'Jane Smith': 'female', 'Peter Apple': 'male'}

sum(gender == "male" for gender in name_to_gender.values())
# 2

sum(gender == "female" for gender in name_to_gender.values())
# 1
```

---

Here are a few asides on coding style. As mentioned in the comments, `list(map(...))` can be ugly. One can replace that with

```py
set(customer.Name for customer in customers)
```

Also, attributes of python classes are often lower-case. It's not a hard rule -- just convention.

Answer (score 0):

If you create pairs/tuples/lists `(name, gender)` then you still can use `set()` to get unique customers and then you can filter them by gender (`pair[1]`) and count them.

---

You can start with

```
m = list(set(map(lambda x: (x.Name, x.Gender), data))
```

to get unique customers but still have access to genders.

And later you can count males (`sum()` will automatically convert `True` into `1` and `False` into `0`)

```
males = sum(x[1] == 'male' for x in m)
```

or if you like `map()`

```
males = sum(map(lambda x: x[1] == 'male', m))
```

The same way you can count females or you can do it simpler

```
females = len(m) - males
```

---

Minimal working code.

I got class and data from @jakub question.

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self, state, name, gender, age, invoiceNo):
        self.State = state
        self.Name = name
        self.Gender = gender
        self.Age = age
        self.Invoice = invoiceNo

data = [
    Customer(state="CA", name="John Doe", gender="male", age=50, invoiceNo=123),
    Customer(state="TX", name="Jane Smith", gender="female", age=40, invoiceNo=401),
    Customer(state="CA", name="John Doe", gender="male", age=50, invoiceNo=680),

    Customer(state="TX", name="Jane Doe", gender="female", age=52, invoiceNo=36524),
    Customer(state="TX", name="Jane Doe", gender="female", age=52, invoiceNo=65142),
    Customer(state="NY", name="John Williams", gender="male", age=68, invoiceNo=24536),

    Customer(state="CA", name="James Bond", gender="male", age=50, invoiceNo=0o7),
]


m = list(set(map(lambda x:(x.Name, x.Gender), data)))

print('m:', m)

#males = sum(x[1] == 'male' for x in m)
males = sum(map(lambda x: x[1] == 'male', m))
print('males:', males)

#females = sum(x[1] == 'female' for x in m)
#females = sum(map(lambda x: x[1] == 'female', m))
females = len(m) - males
print('females:', females)
```

---

**EDIT:**

As @wjandrea noticed in comment there can be `"prefer not to say", "missing", "agender"`, etc. as gender - so using `females = len(m) - males` is good only if you are sure you have only `male`, `female`

---

In some data I saw `Female` instead of `female`, and `Male` instead of `male` - so code would need `lower()`to normalize it

```
lambda x:(x.Name, x.Gender.lower()), data)
```

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't do `females = len(m) - males` cause that assumes that there won't be any other data values like "prefer not to say", "missing", "agender", etc.

Comment: @wjandrea I was thinking about this problem but finally I skiped it in answer.

Comment: @wjandrea I added you comment in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do the various things you asked about. Note that I've added back the class definition you removed from an earlier version of your program and modified it by adding a `unique_id()` and `__repr__()` methods.

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

class Customer:
    def __init__(self, state, name, gender, age, invoice):
        self.State = state
        self.Name = name
        self.Gender = gender
        self.Age = age
        self.Invoice = invoice

    def unique_id(self):
        """ Return identifer unique to this customer. """
        return (self.State, self.Name, self.Gender, self.Age)

    def __repr__(self):
        classname = type(self).__name__
        return (f'{classname}(State={self.State!r}, Name={self.Name!r}, '
                f'Gender={self.Gender!r}, Age={self.Age!r}, invoice={self.Invoice!r})')


filename = 'salesinfo.csv'
data = []

with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')
    next(reader)  # Skip header.
    for row in reader:
        if not row:
            continue
        customer = Customer(row[0], row[1]+" "+row[2], row[3], int(row[4]), int(row[5]))
        data.append(customer)

#pprint(data); print()  # Show what was read.

# Determine number of unique customers (by calling class unique_id() method).
m = list(set(map(lambda c: getattr(c, 'unique_id')(), data)))
print("There are", len(m), "customers")

# Determine how many of each gender there are *and* the overall average age.
seen = set()  # To avoid counting a customer more than once.
genders = dict()
average_age = 0
for customer in data:
    unique_id = customer.unique_id()
    if unique_id not in seen:
        genders[customer.Gender] = genders.setdefault(customer.Gender, 0) + 1
        average_age += customer.Age
        seen.add(unique_id)

average_age = average_age / len(m)

pprint(genders)  # Total number of each gender.
print(f"Average customer's age: {average_age:.1f}")
```